# GG plot legend stacking all shapes / deleting one item from legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

There is a problem with my ggplot, I want to have different shapes for certain values. But in the legend all thing stack on top of each other and therefore the legend is not clear anymore. Moreover, I would like to delete Japan from the legend or find another way to make it red and shape=17. Maybe add to the filter Japan=='FALSE'? I tried but did not succeed...

Here is sample of my data:

```
    structure(list(Country = c("Albania", "Aruba", "Austria", "Barbados", 
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Canada", "China, Hong Kong SAR", "China, Macao SAR", 
"Croatia", "Curaçao", "Denmark", "Finland", "France", "Germany", 
"Iceland", "Italy", "Japan", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Malta", 
"Mauritius", "Montenegro", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Poland", 
"Portugal", "Republic of Korea", "Serbia", "Singapore", "Slovenia", 
"Sri Lanka", "Taiwan", "Thailand", "Trinidad and Tobago", "United States of America"
), `Dependency Ratio 1990` = c(0.371731839842905, 0.42945960478559, 
0.698167620530499, 0.444513116903726, 0.511357742868368, 0.519783119456753, 
0.444426949479237, 0.30306654331295, 0.723691486939267, 0.424414908111054, 
0.68769508504734, 0.641530173960242, 0.690189226564259, 0.755969184286434, 
0.520917100019657, 0.763735128335739, 0.692461922514607, 0.728970209495916, 
0.655093765838824, 0.556158238426314, 0.308439455191019, 0.551893405455789, 
0.582543266573117, 0.548269437314668, 0.592240027149362, 0.744368260326749, 
0.33818760118961, 0.653157768845158, 0.294237762460344, 0.611402526341597, 
0.354595845574429, 0.391092962761626, 0.331304119150256, 0.35111793456609, 
0.562804979721953), `Average Age 1990` = c(40.3688042387203, 
42.5004114258846, 46.6904752788518, 42.5683625031078, 42.4530074518545, 
44.2409448871874, 42.0677766503007, 39.7173235436725, 46.2329924328207, 
42.2501753565583, 47.1375106133558, 46.3380103826365, 46.6915593676301, 
46.9202073747455, 44.129974503284, 47.1071528898825, 46.6077408054755, 
46.4664135824761, 45.460688263743, 44.9450928096016, 39.2332051727974, 
43.66848, 45.1863467813393, 44.5466909246095, 44.9318462263063, 
46.8407998745322, 39.6873706785703, 45.3128111624097, 39.2982502106955, 
45.1205082490539, 40.2124158913374, 40.9051762916043, 39.4534335710941, 
40.4173693037492, 45.0904477728946), ...4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `Dependency Ratio 2000` = c(0.457221087782508, 0.45940989018547, 
    0.742565467519652, 0.541204030550029, 0.597208883500012, 
    0.622668782217446, 0.473107405821069, 0.344264744501091, 
    0.780230513979289, 0.633789601501269, 0.790840886898238, 
    0.816743961984905, 0.766496601277572, 0.821136017787255, 
    0.572251283384235, 0.849390138872188, 0.927739183233871, 
    0.791488299481733, 0.704545225683664, 0.702609326498817, 
    0.35385418751795, 0.612564625368555, 0.69550083971213, 0.617845149047375, 
    0.611138887992547, 0.758176723785889, 0.399735388267277, 
    0.715467873467691, 0.383896159972764, 0.671137540638121, 
    0.407831309113246, 0.419443507121452, 0.374126385687095, 
    0.409593048372564, 0.615930392620661), `Average Age 2000` = c(42.9309383891972, 
    43.8674007980144, 47.739334648896, 45.3560289004102, 45.2990249348384, 
    46.3058678455289, 44.3575197674921, 42.5567755821042, 47.8706196243093, 
    46.6926342578517, 47.9056748231027, 48.2912968951969, 48.1201704908476, 
    48.7598382100637, 45.3475147626354, 48.7908038019529, 48.7739160208226, 
    47.837540150878, 46.9150297452015, 46.5384376276976, 41.1677637838199, 
    45.6830176554619, 46.9484767952653, 46.0162750047118, 45.6870193241911, 
    47.5083105450284, 41.9472090972845, 46.7580169116961, 42.3830413567395, 
    46.6274879755993, 41.6098644987726, 42.77485916275, 41.5907978667698, 
    41.9719792296039, 46.2781534087236), ...7 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), `Dependency Ratio 2015` = c(0.769855001031037, 0.896573728647162, 
    0.952116351996821, 0.847635802309437, 0.907658891504387, 
    0.913339561634508, 0.877436210055064, 0.597279210234922, 
    1.04631340359464, 1.01174318826707, 0.977891738355926, 1.08472890326446, 
    1.01372962185931, 1.12997699958302, 0.77882885539859, 1.08347132170333, 
    1.20679093156161, 0.990147667477283, 0.994357961860711, 0.950194923573131, 
    0.666562280517562, 0.828817278052088, 0.989460150334804, 
    0.831814166715077, 0.847326002560978, 1.03326726133893, 0.749863481391909, 
    0.917215066264046, 0.671774028057953, 0.971441198307662, 
    0.611354032233621, 0.748057645284422, 0.665957813686028, 
    0.602213503073687, 0.855245238291093), `Average Age 2015` = c(46.3902100558352, 
    47.9818955923079, 49.878498965043, 48.4578763127188, 48.3870694416244, 
    48.7063314226308, 48.5131007402609, 44.1281261495054, 50.522561636728, 
    49.6455293947711, 49.9810732770387, 50.7119476819108, 50.6805196046482, 
    51.5236122201751, 47.3079677856577, 51.8838669025279, 53.2344169277342, 
    50.0674941000466, 49.9057070057583, 49.1748722211516, 45.3413745873924, 
    47.6617051653597, 49.9107746561504, 48.0022465682781, 48.1684244717051, 
    51.1526322354916, 47.160655712273, 49.0269050604693, 45.5481140676913, 
    50.0264456515826, 44.8882173741791, 47.0138589294768, 46.131374630996, 
    44.5204789350954, 48.0998439723386), `rgdpe 1990` = c(12005.7568359375, 
    2575.25561523438, 208007.234375, 4099.8515625, 6946.330078125, 
    915724.6875, 151044.28125, 9127.78125, 64448.71484375, NA, 
    144018.203125, 136194.359375, 1581529.625, 2204488.5, 8510.248046875, 
    1560881.5, 3552613.25, 44957.03515625, 53623.6875, 5354.54541015625, 
    11257.8095703125, 6702.1552734375, 427072.25, 76859.65625, 
    335254.875, 157535.140625, 565140.75, 113435.8046875, 64860.5703125, 
    42714.70703125, 55257.37109375, 430917.25, 308367.4375, 15085.6611328125, 
    9847675), `pop 1990` = c(3.286073, 0.062149, 7.723949, 0.260936, 
    4.463423, 27.541319, 5.727938, 0.343808, 4.776374, NA, 5.141115, 
    4.996222, 58.235697, 79.053984, 0.255043, 57.048236, 124.50524, 
    2.664439, 3.696035, 0.362015, 1.055868, 0.615002, 14.965448, 
    3.398172, 37.960193, 9.895364, 42.918419, 9.517675, 3.012966, 
    2.006405, 17.325773, 20.278946, 56.558186, 1.221116, 252.120309
    ), `emp 1990` = c(1.32407820224762, NA, 3.56034135818481, 
    0.105200000107288, 1.68987882137299, 13.2902002334595, 2.73075985908508, 
    0.16329999268055, 2.17813229560852, NA, 2.63417220115662, 
    2.47324681282043, 23.6595039367676, 39.5477294921875, 0.138074412941933, 
    22.8031978607178, 65.1040191650391, 1.25425291061401, 1.70560574531555, 
    0.132750615477562, 0.403737008571625, 0.174824863672256, 
    6.80782461166382, 1.52131986618042, 15.0829668045044, 4.46721506118774, 
    18.2060832977295, 4.61394643783569, 1.52955627441406, 1.1292530298233, 
    5.04270553588867, 8.64918994903564, 28.7045097351074, 0.374099999666214, 
    123.046020507812), ...5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `rgdpe 2000` = c(15180.880859375, 
    4031.13427734375, 314579.6875, 6460.9755859375, 21482.595703125, 
    1276875.5, 256729.140625, 13199.31640625, 58379.2734375, 
    NA, 203091.515625, 186055.46875, 2135621.25, 3030253, 11653.5791015625, 
    2081385.625, 4696670.5, 26473.306640625, 42346.78125, 9706.8212890625, 
    18593.318359375, 4850.50634765625, 691869.625, 114914.1171875, 
    563679.1875, 259576.953125, 1150272, 60002.0703125, 166273.53125, 
    48606.53125, 90442.875, 789527.25, 504829.28125, 18303.63671875, 
    14110581), `pop 2000` = c(3.129243, 0.090853, 8.069276, 0.271515, 
    3.751176, 30.588383, 6.606327, 0.427782, 4.428075, NA, 5.341194, 
    5.187954, 60.874357, 81.400882, 0.280435, 56.692178, 127.524174, 
    2.384164, 3.501839, 0.393645, 1.185145, 0.613559, 15.926188, 
    3.858999, 38.556693, 10.297112, 47.379241, 7.516346, 4.028871, 
    1.987717, 18.777601, 22.18453, 62.952642, 1.267153, 281.710909
    ), `emp 2000` = c(0.962967455387115, 0.0419000014662743, 
    3.7599310874939, 0.12899999320507, 0.643303751945496, 14.952766418457, 
    3.20262169837952, 0.195299997925758, 1.67029082775116, NA, 
    2.75595617294312, 2.30501818656921, 25.6252250671387, 39.6031150817871, 
    0.1570855230093, 22.91796875, 65.9155044555664, 0.930018603801727, 
    1.40124833583832, 0.146938025951385, 0.464872002601624, 0.176752656698227, 
    8.20334815979004, 1.81842231750488, 14.4786930084229, 5.076171875, 
    21.4411239624023, 3.0847954750061, 2.08465480804443, 0.917375922203064, 
    6.30462980270386, 9.59665679931641, 31.47385597229, 0.503100037574768, 
    138.636108398438), ...9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `rgdpe 2015` = c(32037.935546875, 
    3959.59252929688, 448794.71875, 4856.21044921875, 40599.22265625, 
    1659691.75, 411350.65625, 62493.578125, 99181.7265625, 4041.00463867188, 
    278112.53125, 237412.921875, 2772463.25, 3915258.25, 16865.345703125, 
    2296760.75, 5094436, 51517.390625, 87529.2890625, 17455.76171875, 
    25619.560546875, 10165.248046875, 872643.75, 174613.65625, 
    1069768.375, 314019.625, 1928056.875, 108470.875, 451476.4375, 
    68875.1796875, 242116.15625, 1125999, 1108115.875, 38140.46484375, 
    18905122), `pop 2015` = c(2.890513, 0.104341, 8.67866, 0.285324, 
    3.429361, 36.026676, 7.185996, 0.602085, 4.232874, 0.159847, 
    5.688695, 5.481122, 66.596315, 81.787411, 0.330243, 60.578494, 
    127.985133, 1.997674, 2.93188, 0.433559, 1.259456, 0.626956, 
    16.938499, 4.614532, 38.034079, 10.368351, 50.823093, 7.095383, 
    5.592152, 2.071199, 20.908027, 23.462914, 68.714511, 1.370328, 
    320.87831), `emp 2015` = c(0.926395297050476, 0.0467174984514713, 
    4.27823972702026, 0.128199994564056, 0.616872131824493, 18.3558368682861, 
    3.77715754508972, 0.396699994802475, 1.69973313808441, 0.0617999993264675, 
    2.83158588409424, 2.52453279495239, 27.3850765228271, 42.5355796813965, 
    0.181162342429161, 24.4446144104004, 66.9830322265625, 0.897909104824066, 
    1.35488307476044, 0.191138163208961, 0.563370883464813, 0.221699982881546, 
    8.80725860595703, 2.36527323722839, 15.8249969482422, 4.60829973220825, 
    26.079252243042, 2.56693267822266, 3.65548992156982, 0.950674414634705, 
    7.83100032806396, 11.1978015899658, 37.9529876708984, 0.623300015926361, 
    150.248474121094), GDP_per_capita_1990 = c(3653.52712369369, 
    41436.7989064084, 26930.1667288326, 15712.0963090566, 1556.27868524337, 
    33249.1224367286, 26369.74793547, 26549.0659030622, 13493.2303968973, 
    NA, 28013.0289100711, 27259.4691298745, 27157.3915394195, 
    27885.8621470614, 33367.895009371, 27360.7320654051, 28533.8452421762, 
    16872.9834521451, 14508.4360672991, 14790.949021881, 10662.1372845019, 
    10897.7780128154, 28537.2178634412, 22617.9417198423, 8831.74843183753, 
    15920.0955745539, 13167.790500391, 11918.4364550691, 21527.1497628915, 
    21289.1749329024, 3189.31634933402, 21249.4894951641, 5452.2158383934, 
    12353.995142814, 39059.4277750151), GDP_per_capita_2015 = c(11083.8233721402, 
    37948.5775418759, 51712.4439429589, 17019.9858729681, 11838.7135843237, 
    46068.41191788, 57243.3739526156, 103795.274961177, 23431.2966940429, 
    25280.4534252872, 48888.6346077615, 43314.6574506096, 41630.8807777127, 
    47871.1601471283, 51069.5024667442, 37913.7974278463, 39804.9045274657, 
    25788.6875561278, 29854.3218216639, 40261.5600616064, 20341.7670382094, 
    16213.6546214966, 51518.3635810942, 37839.9491541071, 28126.5749855544, 
    30286.3613509998, 37936.6300079375, 15287.5292285138, 80733.9352542635, 
    33253.7721809927, 11580.0575659291, 47990.5863355251, 16126.3735835943, 
    27833.0916713006, 58916.7962147395), change_log_GDP_per_cap_1990_2015 = c(1.10979365523243, 
    -0.0879373277889428, 0.652451349776046, 0.0799574118764497, 
    2.02907746023446, 0.326099133412088, 0.775094455358737, 1.36342588458029, 
    0.551884486717116, NA, 0.556875228192604, 0.46309013522626, 
    0.427192960710386, 0.540393411165555, 0.425593287986558, 
    0.32620624489414, 0.332899198982464, 0.424222198470275, 0.721599336011078, 
    1.00138172800831, 0.645977367508866, 0.39729484866726, 0.590729193215088, 
    0.514621927745218, 1.15836185302803, 0.643115306926695, 1.05814340225474, 
    0.248950929776939, 1.32184407992377, 0.44596948530371, 1.28947786000817, 
    0.814672002339478, 1.08443394063506, 0.812246156576203, 0.411041939497887
    ), change_dependency_ratio_1990_2015 = c(0.398123161188132, 
    0.467114123861573, 0.253948731466323, 0.403122685405711, 
    0.396301148636019, 0.393556442177755, 0.433009260575827, 
    0.294212666921972, 0.322621916655375, 0.587328280156014, 
    0.290196653308586, 0.44319872930422, 0.323540395295048, 0.374007815296586, 
    0.257911755378933, 0.319736193367588, 0.514329009047002, 
    0.261177457981367, 0.339264196021887, 0.394036685146817, 
    0.358122825326543, 0.2769238725963, 0.406916883761686, 0.283544729400408, 
    0.255085975411616, 0.288899001012185, 0.411675880202299, 
    0.264057297418888, 0.377536265597609, 0.360038671966065, 
    0.256758186659192, 0.356964682522796, 0.334653694535773, 
    0.251095568507597, 0.29244025856914)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-35L))
```

And this is my code:

```
#Adding OECD
#Exclude japan for fig
OECD <- c("Dem. People's Republic of Korea",'Mexico','Chile',
          'New Zealand','Czechia','Hungary','Slovakia','Denmark','Estonia',
          'Finland','Iceland','Ireland','Latvia','Lithuania','Norway',
          'Sweden','United Kingdom','Greece','Italy','Portugal','Slovenia',
          'Spain','Austria','Belgium','France','Germany','Luxembourg',
          'Netherlands','Switzerland','Australia','Canada','United States of America',
          'Poland','Turkey','Israel')

#Figure 2
library(tidyverse)
df  %>%
  mutate(OECD = factor(Country %in% OECD, labels = c("NonOECD","OECD"))) %>% mutate(Japan = factor(Country == 'Japan' , labels=c('FALSE','TRUE')))-> newdata

ggplot() +  
  geom_point(data = filter(newdata, OECD == 'NonOECD'),aes(x = change_dependency_ratio_1990_2015, y = change_log_GDP_per_cap_1990_2015, colour='NonOECD'),shape = 16, size=3) +
   geom_point(data = filter(newdata, Japan == 'TRUE'),aes(x = change_dependency_ratio_1990_2015, y = change_log_GDP_per_cap_1990_2015,colour='Japan'),shape = 17, size=4) +
  geom_point(data = filter(newdata, OECD == 'OECD'),aes(x = change_dependency_ratio_1990_2015, y = change_log_GDP_per_cap_1990_2015, colour='OECD' ),shape = 18, size=4) + 
  
  scale_color_manual(values = c(NonOECD = "cyan4", OECD = "orange",Japan='red'),
                     labels = c(NonOECD = "All Countries except OECD", OECD = "OECD countries")) + geom_abline(size=1, col='grey')+
  
  theme_classic()+ theme( panel.grid.major.y =element_line(color='grey', size=0.7),legend.title = element_blank(),
                          panel.grid.minor.y =element_blank(), 
                          legend.background = element_blank(), legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"),
                          legend.spacing.y = unit(0, "mm"),legend.direction = 'horizontal',
                          legend.position = "bottom",aspect.ratio = 0.7, axis.text = element_text(colour = 1, size = 13),)
```

Example of what I got:
[image]

And what it should look like:
[image]

Thanking you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below produces a plot equivalent to the expected output.
The two main differences are:

1. There is no data for `"Japan"` in the question so I have substituted `"Portugal"` (my country) for it;
2. There is no `GDP` data, logged or not so I have created a new column with random uniform numbers, `runif`.

The plot is in fact simple, to create the factor `OECD` start by creating a logical vector, then use an `ifelse` to assign an integer value to the *special country*, in this case `"Portugal"` and add 2 to the other logical vector's elements, giving `FALSE/TRUE + 2 == 0/1 + 2`.

In order not to mix the plot with the theme, I have also created a custom theme, with code at the end.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(2021)

df %>% 
  mutate(OECD = Location %in% OECD,
         OECD = ifelse(Location == "Portugal", 1L, OECD + 2L),
         OECD = factor(OECD, labels = c("Portugal", "NonOECD","OECD"))) %>% 
  mutate(GDP = runif(n(), -2, 2)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = `Dependency Ratio`, y = GDP, color = OECD, shape = OECD, size = OECD)) +  
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(NonOECD = "cyan4", OECD = "orange", Portugal = 'red'),
    labels = c(NonOECD = "All Countries except OECD", OECD = "OECD countries", Portugal = "Portugal")
  ) + 
  scale_shape_manual(
    values = c(NonOECD = 16, OECD = 18, Portugal = 17),
    labels = c(NonOECD = "All Countries except OECD", OECD = "OECD countries", Portugal = "Portugal")
  ) +
  scale_size_manual(
    values = c(NonOECD = 4, OECD = 3, Portugal = 4),
    labels = c(NonOECD = "All Countries except OECD", OECD = "OECD countries", Portugal = "Portugal")
  ) +
  geom_abline(size = 1, col = 'grey') +
  theme_custom_Cas()
```

[image]

---

In order to remove the special country from the legend, subset the data. The code below will output the `%>%` pipe to a new data set and used it in the plot.

```
set.seed(2021)

df %>% 
  mutate(OECD = Location %in% OECD,
         OECD = ifelse(Location == "Portugal", 1L, OECD + 2L),
         OECD = factor(OECD, labels = c("Portugal", "NonOECD","OECD"))) %>% 
  mutate(GDP = runif(n(), -2, 2)) -> newdata

ggplot(newdata, aes(x = `Dependency Ratio`, y = GDP, color = OECD, shape = OECD, size = OECD)) +  
  geom_point(data = subset(newdata, OECD != "Portugal")) +
  # In the special country's layer the color, shape and size must be
  # outside aes() and show.legend = FALSE
  geom_point(
    data = subset(newdata, OECD == "Portugal"),
    color = "red", shape = 17, size = 4,
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(NonOECD = "cyan4", OECD = "orange", Portugal = 'red'),
    labels = c(NonOECD = "All Countries except OECD", OECD = "OECD countries", Portugal = "Portugal")
  ) + 
  scale_shape_manual(
    values = c(NonOECD = 16, OECD = 18, Portugal = 17),
    labels = c(NonOECD = "All Countries except OECD", OECD = "OECD countries", Portugal = "Portugal")
  ) +
  scale_size_manual(
    values = c(NonOECD = 4, OECD = 3, Portugal = 4),
    labels = c(NonOECD = "All Countries except OECD", OECD = "OECD countries", Portugal = "Portugal")
  ) +
  geom_abline(size = 1, col = 'grey') +
  theme_custom_Cas()
```

[image]

---

In order to have a fill color, the points shapes must be changed. See in `help("points")` the rightmost points, filled in grey. Those shapes allow for a border (`ggplot` aesthetic `color`) and a fill color (`ggplot` aesthetic `fill`).

```
ggplot(newdata, aes(x = `Dependency Ratio`, y = GDP, fill = OECD, shape = OECD, size = OECD)) +  
  geom_point(data = subset(newdata, OECD != "Portugal")) +
  # In the special country's layer the color, shape and size must be
  # outside aes() and show.legend = FALSE
  geom_point(
    data = subset(newdata, OECD == "Portugal"),
    fill = "red", shape = 24, size = 4,
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(NonOECD = "cyan4", OECD = "orange", Portugal = 'red'),
    labels = c(NonOECD = "All Countries except OECD", OECD = "OECD countries", Portugal = "Portugal")
  ) + 
  scale_shape_manual(
    values = c(NonOECD = 21, OECD = 23, Portugal = 24),
    labels = c(NonOECD = "All Countries except OECD", OECD = "OECD countries", Portugal = "Portugal")
  ) +
  scale_size_manual(
    values = c(NonOECD = 4, OECD = 3, Portugal = 4),
    labels = c(NonOECD = "All Countries except OECD", OECD = "OECD countries", Portugal = "Portugal")
  ) +
  geom_abline(size = 1, col = 'grey') +
  theme_custom_Cas()
```

[image]

### Custom theme code.

```
theme_custom_Cas <- function(){ 
  theme_classic() %+replace%    #replace elements we want to change
    theme(
      panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = 'grey', size = 0.7),
      legend.title = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(), 
      legend.background = element_blank(), 
      legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"),
      legend.spacing.y = unit(0, "mm"),
      legend.direction = 'horizontal',
      legend.position = "bottom",
      aspect.ratio = 0.7, 
      axis.text = element_text(colour = 1, size = 13)    
    )
}
```

Comment: I changed the data, I am trying to adjust your code now to see if I can make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Do you perhaps also know how to make the names visible for a certain value and how to only delete japan from legend?

Comment: Sorry for asking so much! But when I add scale_fill_manual to create borders it does not work, it just takes the color of scale_color_manual? And do you know how to add the name tags?

Comment: @Cas The border is now in the 3rd plot. As for text, please post another question or see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585468/ggplot2-add-text-next-to-point-only-if-conditions-are-met). In your expected plot not all points have text so the conditional text in that link might be helpful.